# Audio via DisplayPort - How do I keep it going when Windows 10 turns the display off?

Tags: windows-10, audio, display, nvidia-geforce, displayport

I have connected my Nvidia GTX 970 to a Dell U2713H monitor via a DisplayPort cable, with speakers plugged in to the monitor's audio out 3.5mm port. I have my Windows 10 power setting set up to turn displays off after 30 minutes, and to never put the computer to sleep.

When the display is turned off, the monitor is not actually off, so I would expect that the audio should continue to output to the speakers. I have attempted the registry edit mentioned in this answer (https://superuser.com/a/1235631/1177011), but this seems to specifically be an issue with closing a laptop screen, while I am using a desktop machine, and has not solved my problem.

Is there a way to ensure that the monitor will continue to output audio when the display is turned off? Or am I misunderstanding how audio over DisplayPort works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows never **turns off** a monitor. In reality it turns off the port connected to the monitor and relies on the monitor to turn off as a reaction to a no-link-condition.

Since the audio data is transmitted via the same signalling mechanism as the video data, it is physically impossible to turn off video but not audio on a port.

Comment: Ah. I guess I thought the monitor was instructed to switch to low power mode by a CEC command, rather than just relying on a loss of signal.